# Unable to update tags from portal after assigning policy to inherit tags from subscription

Tags: azure, azure-policy

I have added a custom policy using the built in policy to inherit tags from subscriptions to resource groups and its resources

But after applying policy if i try to edit a tags or run a powershell command to update the tags its not getting updated

```json
{
    "properties": {
        "displayName": "Add multiple tags to resource if missing",
        "policyType": "Custom",
        "mode": "All",
        "description": "Adds multiple tags with its value from the parent resource group when any resource missing this tag is created or updated. Existing resources can be remediated by triggering a remediation task. If the tag exists with a different value it will not be changed.",
        "parameters": {
            "tagName1": {
                "type": "String",
                "metadata": {
                    "displayName": "First Tag Name",
                    "description": "Name of the tag, such as 'environment'"
                }
            },
            "tagName2": {
                "type": "String",
                "metadata": {
                    "displayName": "Second Tag Name",
                    "description": "Name of the tag, such as 'environment'"
                }
            },
        },
        "policyRule": {
            "if": {
                "anyOf": [
                    {
                        "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName1'), ']')]",
                        "notEquals": "[subscription().tags[parameters('tagName1')]]"
                    },
                    {
                        "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName2'), ']')]",
                        "notEquals": "[subscription().tags[parameters('tagName2')]]"
                    },
                ]
            },
            "then": {
                "effect": "modify",
                "details": {
                    "roleDefinitionIds": [
                        "/providers/microsoft.authorization/"
                    ],
                    "operations": [
                        {
                            "operation": "addOrReplace",
                            "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName1'), ']')]",
                            "value": "[subscription().tags[parameters('tagName1')]]"
                        },
                        {
                            "operation": "addOrReplace",
                            "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName2'), ']')]",
                            "value": "[subscription().tags[parameters('tagName2')]]"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am unable to update the tags from portal or powershell after adding this policy

Answer (score -1):

Try creating a duplicate definition/edit a definition and change ***mode value to "All"*** (default is "indexed").

`"mode" : "All"`

I tried in Portal, its inheriting and updating the tags from the subscription.

```json
{
"mode": "All",
"policyRule": {
"if": {
"allOf": [
{
"field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName'), ']')]",
"notEquals": "[subscription().tags[parameters('tagName')]]"
 },
{
"value": "[subscription().tags[parameters('tagName')]]",
"notEquals": ""
  }
 ]
},
"then": {
"effect": "modify",
"details": {
"roleDefinitionIds": [
"/providers/microsoft.authorization/roleDefinitions/xxxxxxxxxxdd24c"
],
"operations": [
{
"operation": "addOrReplace",
"field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName'), ']')]",
"value": "[subscription().tags[parameters('tagName')]]"
}
   ]
 }
}
},
"parameters": {
"tagName": {
"type": "String",
"metadata": {
"displayName": "Tag Name",
"description": "Name of the tag, such as 'environment'"

     }

   }
 }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

After enabling these changes, you can update the tags and it will reflect within the given scope.

*If still the issue persists, create a new Resource Group and check whether the tags are updated after inheriting*.

Comment: Yeah I have the mode set to "All" but the issue is i cannot update the Tags from portal now on subscription scope .. can you test it if it works for you ?

Comment: @ElonMusk Did you find a solution ? I have the same script and the same problem. After Remedietion task i can not manually change tags to test my policy. The goal was to create policy that will update tags based on subscription tags, so if someone change tag - update in resources

Comment: @michasaucer The problem is if you scoped the policy on Subscription . you will not able to update it. Try to scope it little down on all resource RG (policy). then you can update the tags from the portal on Resource group  and the inheritance will work automatically